# Issue with cylindrical integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

I am trying to integrate over the region $E = E_{1} \cap E_{2} \cap E_{3}$, where $E_{1} = \{(x, y, z): y\geq0\}$, $E_{2} = \{(x, y, z): x^{2} + z^{2} \leq 4\}$, $E_{3} = \{(x, y, z): x+y+z \leq 3\}$.

Intuitively, this is a cylinder of radius 2 along the y-axis from $y=0$ until it is cut off by the plane defined by $E_{3}$.  Which led me to my integral:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^{3-rsin(\theta)-rcos(\theta)} \!r\, \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$

Which yields $12\pi$.  My problem is, I get the same answer if I integrate:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^3 \!r\, \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$

Clearly, the latter defines a larger space than the former, since the first one is the same cylinder but with a chunk sliced off.  Thus, I have to be defining my integral wrong to be getting the same volume for both.  Can someone show the the proper way to do this?

Comment: The volume is not smaller - what is the maximum possible $y$ ? You'll see that its cross section is a trapezoid where $3$ is the average height.

Comment: Oh god wait you’re saying that from the nature of the bounds it extends past $y=3$ to some larger value, and averages out to $3$.  Thank you so much—I’m not sure why that didn’t click for me.

Comment: You're very welcome! Don't worry about it, it's easy to forget that values (in this case $x$ and $z$) can be negative sometimes.